# htaccess issue with non-www redirect and trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, slash

I currently redirect all traffic to the `www.` version of my site. However, upon checking redirected links in a specific folder, I've noticed something that may / may not be an issue.

Basically, if I do a header check on `www.example.com/example/examplepage/` it shows 200 OK.

If I check `www.example.com/example/examplepage` (without trailing `/`) it shows 301 redirect to the above as it should.

BUT, if I check `example.com/example/examplepage/` (without `www`), it redirects to `www.example.com/example/examplepage.php` ... which then redirects to `www.example.com/example/examplepage/` (the correct page).

I hope this makes sense?

a) is this OK?
 b) am I missing something in my `.htaccess`?

```
  RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.htm$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^tips/([^.]+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/example/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^tips/([^.]+[^./])$ http://www.example.com/example/$1/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^(tips/[^.]+)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

Please note: the above PHP rule was created to "hide" `.php` extensions on a specific folder (didn't want them hidden anywhere else).

Comment: It's not clear why `www.example.com/example/examplepage` should redirect (this implies that all URLs should end in a trailing slash)? However, according to your directives, only URL-paths that start `/tips/` would redirect?

Comment: yes, that's right - this redirect only applies to the /tips folder. Maybe I should have made this clearer the "tips" reference should have been changed to "example" to fit in with the example.com references - sorry...hope this makes sense.

Comment: I see you've changed your example to read: "if I check `example.com/example/examplepage/` (without www), it redirects to `www.example.com/example/examplepage.php` ..." - I don't see how that would happen with the directives you have posted?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  IT basically 301 redirects twice - once to /examplepage.php and then again to the correct page.  Is this OK?  I was trying to get all redirects to the one URL using just one 301 redirect but I just don't think it's going to be possible. Appreciate you getting back to me as my original post is pretty confusing!!

Comment: Redirecting twice is not necessarily a problem. However, redirecting to `/examplepage.php` would be undesirable since you are wanting to _hide_ the `.php` extension. But... as mentioned above, this should not be happening with the directives you posted above?! The first redirect should be the one to `www.example.com/example/examplepage/`. Make sure your browser cache is cleared, as any erroneous 301s will get cached by the browser.

Comment: I managed to work it out (well, ok - got lucky guessing), but either way, it seems to work now.  I've adapted the above rule order to show the following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out (*well, ok - got lucky guessing*), but either way, it seems to work now.  I've adapted the above rule order to show the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^tips/([^.]+)\.php$ http://www.example.com/tips/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^tips/([^.]+[^./])$ http://www.example.com/tips/$1/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.htm$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(tips/[^.]+)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

This now results in:

1. http://example.com/tips/examplepage.php (and www version)
2. http://example.com/tips/examplepage - without trailing slash (and www version)

All finally redirecting to www.example.com/tips/examplepage/ (with trailing slash)

It also ensures www.example.com/examplepage.php (not within the "tips" folder) keeps it's extension.

It also re-writes index.htm to / (using both www and non-www).

I've tried to add as much detail here as possible in the hope it prevents someone else wasting an entire weekend pulling their hair out, going gray etc...